# SQL statement to select all dead people

Tags: sql, datetime, count, subquery

I have tables:

- City:
  `zip, name,...`
- People:
  `id, city_zip(refers to city.zip), born_time, dead_time`

I need to select data about cities where ALL people from that city are dead: `born_time NOT NULL AND dead_time < NOW()`

because we do not assume that someone is dead if we do not have information.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from city c
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from people p1 
    where p1.city_zip = c.zip and (dead_time is null or dead_time > now())
)
```

This would also return cities that have no people at all. If that's something you want to avoid, then another option is aggregation:

```
select c.*
from city c
inner join people p on p.city_zip = c.zip 
group by c.zip
having max(case when dead_time is null or dead_time > now() then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

`select c.* ... from city c ... group by c.zip` is valid standard SQL (assuming that `zip` is the primary key of table `city`). However, all databases do not support it, in which case you will need to enumerate the columns you want in both the `select` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: there always is at least one people in the city, which statement is less "demanding" i.e. is quicker?